# Complex pointer declarations

Tags: c, pointers

I tried the declaration `int * p()[]` in cdecl.org and it says "declare p as function returning array of pointer to int".

According to me, the declaration means "p is array of functions returning pointer to int" and this doesn't make any sense. So this declaration should not be allowed right ?

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You might want to learn about [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). And how to use type-aliases (with `typedef`) to simplify function-pointer declarations.

Comment: They may return arrays if the array is handed over to the function by a pointer.

Comment: @manuel-hoelzl That makes no sense.

Comment: The cdecl.org interpretation is correct, but it is also not allowed.  Functions may not return arrays.  Your interpretation is incorrect. Your description would apply to `int *p[]()`.  Hint:  `p()` is a function, `p[]` is an array.

Comment: "Array of pointers to functions returning int" would be `int (*p[])();`

Comment: For me look like a function pointer returning a pointer to an Array of Int, or I'm wrong? or a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an Array of int.

Comment: @Michi You're wrong. The cdecl.org interpretation is still correct.

Comment: @melpomene You can not return an Array in C

Comment: Shouldn't it be interpreted as " p is a function returning a pointer to an array of integers" like int * (p()) [] according to spiral rule

Comment: @SagarP That was my Point too.

Comment: @Michi , Ya, I don't understand why is out interpretation wrong.

Comment: @Michi That's why the declaration is an error.

Comment: @melpomene I think it should be `int (*p())[];`

Comment: The spiral rule will show you why you're wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration indeed should not be allowed; functions may not return array types, and you may not have arrays of function type:

> **6.7.6.2 Array declarators**
> **Constraints**
> 1 In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
> an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
> expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
> have a value greater than zero. **The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
> type.** The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a
> declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
> array type derivation.
>
> ...
>
> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> **Constraints**
> 1 **A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array
> type.**

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  I don't know why cdecl doesn't return some kind of error on that.

If you want a function that returns a pointer to an array, you'd write

```
int (*p())[N];
```

This parses as

```
      p         -- p is a
      p()       -- function returning
     *p()       -- pointer to
    (*p())[N]   -- array of 
int (*p())[N];  -- int
```

If you want an array of function pointers, you'd write

```
int (*p[N])();
```

which parses as

```
      p        -- p is an
      p[N]     -- array of
     *p[N]     -- pointer to
    (*p[N])()  -- function returning
int (*p[N])(); -- int
```

If you want a function that returns a pointer to an array of pointers, you'd write

```
int *(*p())[N];
```

which reads as

```
       p         -- p is a
       p()       -- function returning
      *p()       -- pointer to
     (*p())[N]   -- array of
    *(*p())[N]   -- pointer to
int *(*p())[N];  -- int
```

Postfix `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so:

```
T *a[N];   // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N]; // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();    // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();  // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Starting with those rules, you can use substitution to build more complex declarations.  If you want a function returning a pointer to an array, take

```
T (*a)[N];
```

and replace `a` with a function declarator:

```
T (*  a  )[N];
      |
      V
T (* f() )[N];
```

If you want an array of pointers to functions, take a function pointer declarator

```
T (*f)();
```

and replace `f` with an array declarator:

```
T (*   f   )()
       |
       V
T (*  a[N] )();
```

From here, you should be able to read (and generate) more complex types.

cdecl's a nice tool, but once you learn how C declaration syntax really works, you shouldn't need it anymore.

Comment: How does cdecl declare it as "returns an array of int". If we have a simple declaration like int * a[10] , we read it as "array of 10 integer pointer and not as 'a' returns an array of 10 integer pointers". So int * f() [10 ] should also be read as f is function of 10 integer pointers which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SagarP: Again, `cdecl` shouldn’t return *anything* but “this is not a legal declaration.”. But, they get there as follows - postfix `()` and `[]` have the same precedence, and they bind left-to-right.  `f()[10]` is parsed as `(f())[10]` - “`f` is a function returning an array”.  Again, C doesn’t allow functions to return array types, so wondering why cdecl interprets it the way it does is kind of waste of time.